# How to keep items hidden after clean search?

Tags: javascript, haml

I built a FAQ page and implemented a search function using JavaScript.
All the list of items are initially hidden and when I type a keyword in the search bar, the result shows.
But, I have a problem after empty the keyword in the search bar.

After I type something and then empty, the list of all items remains as visible, however, I want to keep them hidden.

[image]

My **index.html.haml** (It's a long list so I show some as reference)

```
%input#myInput{:onkeyup => "findFAQ()", :placeholder => "Search for questions", :title => "Type keywords", :type => "text"}

%ul#faqall
      %li
        %button.hidden.faq-toggle-list Where can I apply?
        .highlight
          %div.hidden
            apply in person at your local office. We are looking forward to hearing from you!
      %li
        %button.hidden.faq-toggle-list When can I expect to hear back from you?
        .highlight
          %div.hidden
            we will contact you for an interview 
      %li
        %button.hidden.faq-toggle-list Do you have any jobs available?
        .highlight
          %div.hidden
            Yes! Please visit us at
      %li
        %button.hidden.faq-toggle-list Do I sign up online or come to the office?
        .highlight
          %div.hidden
            Yes! Please visit us
            
      %li
        %button.hidden.faq-toggle-list I want to work in a specific industry only, can you help me?
        .highlight
          %div.hidden
            We work across all industries and all verticals.
```

**faq.js**

```
function findFAQ() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("faqall");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
      
      a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
      txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          a.style.display = "block";
          
          
      } else {
          a.style.display = "none";
          
      }
}
}
```

**faq.scss**

```
.hidden {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: My advice would be *don't* hide all the useful information behind a search. Use it to *filter*.

Comment: That would be a possible way. But, I want to keep the way as there are other contents below the Q&A. I want the visitors to be able to see them at the first view. If I don't hide that long list of questions (about 50), visitors will have to scroll down a while to see other content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change the if below

```
if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
```

to

```
  if (filter && txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
```

and it will work

Comment: This was what I was looking for. Thanks!!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. But just to inform you that SO has a "thanks" reaction near the accept checkmark. Thanking in comments is discouraged because it constitutes around 20% of all user comments on SO and it's not useful for other readers. :)